# Swift - Can I make a protocol Hashable?

Tags: swift, protocols, hashable

I have written a simple protocol `Data` :

```
public protocol Data {
    var state: [String: Any] { get set }    
    var objectId: String? { get set }    
}

public extension Data {
    var objectId: String? {
        get {
            return self.state["objectId"] as? String
        }
        set {
            self.state["objectId"] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

This way, I have created several types conforming to it:

```
public struct Person: Data {
    public var state: [String : Any]
}
public struct Car: Data {
    public var state: [String : Any]
}
// ...
```

Now what I want to do is to make each of these types `Hashable`, the problem is that I need to write this code in every type:

```
extension Car Hashable {
    public static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        return lhs.objectId == rhs.objectId
    }        
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.objectId ?? "")
    }    
}
// ...
```

What I want to know is if it is possible to generically declare `Data` as `Hashable` from its `objectId`. As I am using a protocol, I couldn't find a way to do so.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Using `[String:Any]` breaks auto-synthesis for the `Hashable` conformance. Storing `state` as `[String:Any]` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Data is a native Swift type you should use another name for your protocol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Leo Dabus mentioned in his comment, you should probably use another name for your protocol due to native `Foundation.Data` type existence.

Either way, using the following code you can implement `Hashable` protocol into your `Data` protocol:

```
public protocol Data: Hashable {
    var state: [String: Any] { get set }
    var objectId: String? { get set }
}

public extension Data {
    var objectId: String? {
        get {
            return self.state["objectId"] as? String
        }
        set {
            self.state["objectId"] = newValue
        }
    }
    
    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.objectId == rhs.objectId
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.objectId ?? "")
    }
}
```

Although this will have as a side effect that protocol `Data` can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements:

[image]

Meaning that you can now on use the `Data` protocol like this:

```
func myFunc<T: Data>(data: T) {
    
}
```